# I probably have problem with float specifiers? But I cant figure out what can be wrong

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, vertical-alignment, vertical

so basically, the last .tex file is annoying me greatly. This one is included between two more files, (one of them includes 6 sidetables), and my problem is that LaTeX (or the arguments I put in preamble) wont insert floats correctly, so the text would flow nicely, also one of the chapters is inserted between tables. I can include the preamble or the whole project, so you can see what exactly is wrong.

I think it has something to do with float locants like [h],[H] etc, but I am not able to fix it by myself anymore, everything I try screws me up even more.

Any help very greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Neionizované látky}

Neionizované látky hexobarbital a oxazepam sloužily k potvrzení naší teorie. Hexobarbital je velmi slabá kyselina (pK\textsubscript{A} = 8,21), zatímco oxazepam je velmi slabou bazí (pK\textsubscript{A} = 11,65). Za uvedených chromatografických podmínek jsou obě látky v nedisociované podobě. Předpokládali jsme, že díky tomu nedochází k elektrostatickým interakcím s kovovými nečistotami na povrchu silikagelu. Tento předpoklad reflektuje výsledky již dříve provedených experimentů. \cite{danekVyuzitiHPLCChiralnich2019}. 

\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\catcode`\-=12\
\caption{Vliv experimentálních podmínek na chirální separaci neionizovaných látek za použití MF 1 a MF 2.}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc c ccccc}
\hline
Vzorek & Chirální separace & k\textsubscript{1} & k\textsubscript{2} & Rozlišení && Vzorek & Chirální separace & k\textsubscript{1} & k\textsubscript{2} & Rozlišení \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{MF 1} : ACN-AcA (0,1M, pH 5,6), (10:90, \textit{v/v})} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{MeOH-AcA (0,1M, pH 5,6), (10:90, \textit{v/v})} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & eluce po 55 minutách & -  & -  & - && hexobarbital & - & - & -  & -  \\
oxazepam & ano & 2,07  & 4,31  & 6,86 && oxazepam & ano & 4,60 & 9,97  & 7,41  \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{c}{20\% ACN} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{20\% MeOH} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 3,66  & 4,19  & 1,74 && hexobarbital & ano & 15,30 & 17,72  & 1,98  \\
oxazepam & ano & 0,56  & 1,06  & 3,44 && oxazepam & ano & 2,39 & 4,97  & 6,32  \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% ACN} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% MeOH} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 0,73  & 0,84  & 0,83 && hexobarbital & ano & 4,46 & 5,14  & 1,73  \\
oxazepam & ano & 0,00  & 0,16  & 0,54 && oxazepam & ano & 0,75 & 1,43  & 3,72  \\

\hline
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{MF 2} : ACN-H\textsubscript{2}O, (20:80, \textit{v/v})} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{MeOH-H\textsubscript{2}O, (20:80, \textit{v/v})} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 4,56  & 5,10  & 0,10 && hexobarbital & ano & 17,56 & 20,27  & 1,70  \\
oxazepam & ano & 0,88  & 0,97  & 2,24 && oxazepam & ano & 2,46 & 5,27  & 5,72  \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% ACN} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% MeOH} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 0,88  & 0,97  & 0,32 && hexobarbital & ano & 6,14 & 6,94  & 1,32  \\
oxazepam & ano & -0,02 & 0,63  & 0,37 && oxazepam & ano & 0,88 & 1,69  & 3,36  \\

\hline
\hline


\end{tabular}
\label{neutralymf1_2}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\catcode`\-=12\
\caption{Vliv experimentálních podmínek na chirální separaci neionizovaných látek za použití MF 3 a MF 4.}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc c ccccc}
\hline
Vzorek & Chirální separace & k\textsubscript{1} & k\textsubscript{2} & Rozlišení && Vzorek & Chirální separace & k\textsubscript{1} & k\textsubscript{2} & Rozlišení \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{MF 3} : ACN-EDTA (1,25mM), (20:80, \textit{v/v})} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{MeOH-EDTA (1,25mM), (20:80, \textit{v/v})} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 4,85 & 5,56  & 1,33 && hexobarbital & ano & 18,26 & 21,18  & 2,19  \\
oxazepam & ano & 0,78  & 1,41  & 3,07 && oxazepam & ano & 3,09 & 6,32  & 5,72  \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% ACN} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% MeOH} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 1,09  & 1,21  & 0,55 && hexobarbital & ano & 5,45 & 6,32  & 1,38  \\
oxazepam & ano & 0,21  & 0,32 & 0,57 && oxazepam & ano & 0,93 & 1,77  & 3,32  \\

\hline
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{MF 4} : ACN-AcA (0,1M, pH 3,2), (10:90, \textit{v/v})} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{MeOH-AcA (0,1M, pH 3,2), (10:90, \textit{v/v})} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & - & - & - & - && hexobarbital & - & - & -  & - \\
oxazepam & ano & 1,84 & 3,79  & 5,83 && oxazepam & ano & 4,13 & 8,67  & 5,15  \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{c}{20\% ACN} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{20\% MeOH} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 3,32  & 3,80  & 1,42 && hexobarbital & ano & 12,85 & 15,05  & 1,79  \\
oxazepam & ano & 0,58 & 1,06  & 2,37 && oxazepam & ano & 2,16 & 4,43  & 5,25  \\

\hline

\multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% ACN} && \multicolumn{5}{c}{35\% MeOH} \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
hexobarbital & ano & 0,80  & 0,90  & 0,61 && hexobarbital & ano & 4,21 & 4,83  & 1,36  \\
oxazepam & ano & 0,17 & 0,25  & 0,42 && oxazepam & ano & 0,76 & 1,42  & 2,96  \\

\hline
\hline

\end{tabular}
\label{neutralymf3_4}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Ve všech použitých mobilních fázích docházelo k chirální separaci obou látek. Při stejných koncentracích organické složky byla vyšší retence a rozlišení za použití metanolu. Hexobarbital byl výrazně více zadržován nežli oxazepam. Naměřené retenční faktory lze nalézt v tabulkách č. \ref{neutralymf1_2} a \ref{neutralymf3_4}. V případě oxazepamu byl také pozorován tzv. batman pík, což ukazuje na přechod jednoho enantiomeru oxazepamu v druhý během analýzy. Tento proces je závislý na teplotě a jejím snížením by došlo ke snížení sedla mezi píky. \cite{polavarapuchiralanalysis2018} 


Vysvětlení větší retence hexobarbitalu může spočívat v částečné ionizaci látky a iontových interakcí s povrchem silikagelu či v komplexaci analytu s kovem na povrchu nebo v nespecifické absorpci. \cite{danekVyuzitiHPLCChiralnich2019} Na obrázku č. \ref{grafyneutraly} jsou uvedeny chromatogramy hexobarbitalu.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{pictures/grafy_neutraly.PNG}
    \caption{Chromatogramy hexobarbitalu v jednotlivých mobilních fázích při koncentraci 35\% ACN.}
   \label{grafyneutraly}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Testován byl i vliv kovových nečistot na retenční chování analytů v nedisociované podobě pomocí EDTA. Předpokládali jsme, že kovové nečistoty nebudou mít na retenční chování vliv. Na základě naměřených dat byl ke zkoumání vlivu EDTA na achirální interakce použit 20\% acetonitril se zvyšujícím se koncentrací EDTA (1,25 mM, 5 mM, 10 mM, 20 mM a 40 mM). Naměřené výsledky pro hexobarbital a oxazepam jsou k dispozici v tabulce č. \ref{edtaneioniz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 \textbf{Koncentrace (mM)} & \textbf{k\textsubscript{1}} & \textbf{k\textsubscript{2}} & \textbf{Rozlišení} & \textbf{w\textsubscript{1}} & \textbf{w\textsubscript{2}}\\ 
 \hline \hline
 \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{hexobarbital}\\
 \hline
 \textbf{1,25} & 4,85 & 5,56 & 1,33 & 1,04 & 1,14  \\ 
 \textbf{5} & 4,32 & 4,96 & 1,57 & 1,07 & 1,21\\ 
 \textbf{10} & 4,66 & 5,37 & 1,67 & 1,17 & 1,28 \\
 \textbf{20} & 4,47 & 5,13 & 1,45 & 1,19 & 1,46 \\
 \textbf{40} & 4,05 & 4,65 & 1,44 & 1,11 & 1,44 \\
 \hline 
 \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{oxazepam}\\
 \hline
  \textbf{1,25} & 0,78 & 1,41 & 3,07 & 0,52 & 0,64  \\ 
 \textbf{5} & 0,74 & 1,34 & 3,03 & 0,51 & 0,61\\ 
 \textbf{10} & 0,80 & 1,49 & 3,37 & 0,54 & 0,67 \\
 \textbf{20} & 0,74 & 1,40 & 3,15 & 0,52 & 0,66 \\
 \textbf{40} & 0,65 & 1,20 & 2,82 & 0,53 & 0,62 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Vliv koncentrace EDTA na retenční chování hexobarbitalu a oxazepamu v ACN-EDTA, (20:80 \textit{v/v}); k\textsubscript{1,2} - retenční faktory jednotlivých enantiomerů hexobarbitalu, w\textsubscript{1,2} - šířky píků.}
\label{edtaneioniz}
\end{center}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

U hexobarbitalu a oxazepamu bylo pozorováno mírné snížení retenčního faktoru, u hexobarbitalu i snížení rozlišení. Tato změna byla pozorována mezi 20 a 40 mM, viz grafy 6 a 7. 

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={\textbf{Graf 6:} Závislost retenčních faktorů prvnich píků neionizovaných látek na koncentraci EDTA.},
    xlabel={koncentrace EDTA [mM]},
    ylabel={Retenční faktor},
    xmin=0, xmax=50,
    ymin=0.5, ymax=10,
    xtick={1.25,5,10,20,40},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]

    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (1.25,4.84)(5,4.32)(10,4.66)(20,4.47)(40,4.05)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Retenční faktor hexobarbitalu}

    \addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=triangle,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1.25,0.78)(5,0.74)(10,0.79)(20,0.74)(40,0.65)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Retenční faktor oxazepamu}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={\textbf{Graf 7:} Závislost rozlišení píků neionizovaných látek na koncentraci EDTA.},
    xlabel={koncentrace EDTA [mM]},
    ylabel={Rozlišení},
    xmin=0, xmax=50,
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    xtick={1.25,5,10,20,40},
    ytick={1,2,3,4,5},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1.25,1.33)(5,1.57)(10,1.67)(20,1.45)(40,1.44)
    };
    \legend{Rozlišení enantiomerů hexobarbitalu}

    \addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {(1.25,3.07)(5,3.03)(10,3.37)(20,3.15)(40,2.82)};
    \addlegendentry{Rozlišení enantiomerů oxazepamu}   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

EDTA chelatuje kationická místa na povrchu silikagelu. Jelikož může docházet k částečné ionizaci hexobarbitalu nebo jeho komplexaci s kovem na povrchu silikagelu, snížení retence je pravděpodobně založené na podkladu ovlivnění achirálních interakcí. Snížení rozlišení lze přisoudit kratší retenci. Vliv zvyšující se koncentrace EDTA na šířku píků nebyl pozorován, viz graf č. 8.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={\textbf{Graf 8:} Závislost šířky prvních píků neionizovaných látek na koncentraci EDTA.},
    xlabel={koncentrace EDTA [mM]},
    ylabel={Šířka píku},
    xmin=0, xmax=50,
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    xtick={1.25,5,10,20,40},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1.25,1.04)(5,1.07)(10,1.17)(20,1.19)(40,1.11)
    };
    \legend{Šířka píku hexobarbitalu}

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {(1.25,0.52)(5,0.51)(10,0.54)(20,0.52)(40,0.53)};
    \addlegendentry{Šířka píku oxazepamu}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Also, here is the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel=true, spacing=true, kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{morewrites}

\usepackage[english, czech]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{german}{czech}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

%chem-angew%

\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=auto,style=chem-acs,isbn=true,articletitle=true,sorting=none,autocite=plain]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./citace.bib}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm, 257mm},
left=25mm,
right=35mm,
}

\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}

\graphicspath{ {pictures/} } % cesta proobrazky

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %nastaveni rovnic nesahat

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\figwidth}{0.8\textwidth} %nastaveni obrazku




\usepackage{caption}







%multi-row
\usepackage{multirow} %tabulky
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{.5cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots} %grafy
\pgfplotsset{width=9.5cm,compat=1.9}



\DeclareMathAlphabet{\vect}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{bx}{sl}
\newcolumntype{\vectgr}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
%nesahat!!!!!




\newcommand*{\ORGeqfloat}{}
\let\ORGeqfloat\eqfloat
\def\eqfloat{%
  \let\ORIGINALcaption\caption
  \def\caption{%
    \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
    \ORIGINALcaption
  }%
  \ORGeqfloat
}





\linespread{1.5} %odstup mezi radky


\usepackage{subfiles} % posledni linka preambule 

%musíš to dát sem
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{eqfloat}{equation}
\newfloat{eqfloat}{h}{eqflts}
\floatname{eqfloat}{Rovnice}
```

Comment: When I put my document into somewhat usable state, with float locators and \clearpage it makes a completely blank page between random sidetables. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: we can't run your example and it is very hard to understand your description of the` float placement so just some general notes. Don't use a `center` environment around floats such as sidewaystable. If you use `[h]` then you are preventing t b or p so not allowing the float at top or bottom of a page  or on a page of floats, so it may have nowhere to go and drift to the end (latex usually warns and changes it to `[ht]`  you mention `[H]` which stops floats but isn't defined by default.